# Cascading configuration with multiple environments?

Tags: eslint

How can I use [cascading configurations](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy) with slightly different environments (one for node.js and one for the browser)? The only real difference between the two environments is the `env` variable.

Ideally I want something like this:

```
my-project
├── .eslintrc.json
├── .eslintrc.node.json
├── .eslintrc.browser.json
└─┬ src
  └── .eslintrc.json
```

Where I instruct ESLint to use the merge of:

- `.eslintrc.json`
- `.eslintrc.node.json`
- `src/.eslintrc.json`

Any ideas?

### What I tried

1. I tried declaring separate `.eslintrc.node.json` and `.eslintrc.browser.json` files. This worked, but cascading configurations did not work (configuration files with similar file names in sub-directories were ignored). This approach also suffers from a lot of duplication between the two files.
2. I tried declaring a single `.eslintrc.json` file and passing a `env` configuratoin to the eslint constructor. The configuration on disk got picked up but the `env` passed to the constructor was ignored.

NOTE: I am interacting with eslint through [gulp-eslint](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint) but I assume that I would see the same behavior if I interacted with eslint directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. [CLIEngine](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#cliengine) takes an "envs" constructor option, so I did the following:

```
gulp.task("lint-for-node", function()
{
    return gulp.src(
        [
            "src/**.js"
        ]).
        pipe(eslint(
            {
                "envs": ["es6", "node", "amd"]
            }
        )).
        pipe(eslint.format()).
        pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

gulp.task("lint-for-browser", function()
{
    return gulp.src(
        [
            "src/**.js"
        ]).
        pipe(eslint(
            {
                "envs": ["es6", "browser"]
            }
        )).
        pipe(eslint.format()).
        pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});
```

Cascading configuration correctly merges `.eslintrc.json` and `src/.eslintrc.json` and ESLint picks up the correct environment from the above constructor.